# How do you pronounce Rx? - Covid-19 Rx

Tags: pronunciation

I temporarily pronounce it as "prescription" because Rx. stands for a doctor's prescription.

> NEJM tweeted:
> **Covid-19 Rx**: Your task is to gather data, develop a differential diagnosis, order additional diagnostic tests, and treat the patient. (Optimized for desktop PCs and most tablets.)

Comment: I would pronounce it RX (individual letters).

Comment: That means: prescription, but people  actually call them "scripts" in colloquial American medical English. However, I do not understand how it is used in the phrase you posted.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_prescription), it's one of those very old _writing_ abbreviations that were used when everything had to be hand-written. I'm not a doctor, but I suspect it would indeed be pronounced _prescription_.

Comment: That company, NEJM, is using that title for a treatment simulator for medical professionals. https://covid19rx.nejm.org/landing/index.html A bad choice for a title, in my opinion. As a TITLE, the letters would be pronounced R and X.

Comment: In context since it is the name of an app I think RX as @Void suggests is best although in other contexts prescriptions or scripts is usual as others have suggested.

Comment: I am surprised to see people saying _script_ here: to me, it has always been _scrip_. However, I see that both are attested in the OED.